# Abstract property with public getter, define private setter in concrete class possible?

Tags: c#, properties, abstract-class, setter, getter

I'm trying to create an abstract class that defines a property with a getter. I want to leave it up to derived classes to decide if they want to implement a setter for the property or not. Is this possible?

What I have so far:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract string Value { get; }
    public void DoSomething() {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }
}

public class ConcreteClass1 : AbstractClass {
    public override string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteClass2 : AbstractClass {
    private string _value;
    public override string Value {
        get { return _value; }
    }
    public string Value {
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}

public class ConcreteClass3 : AbstractClass {
    private string _value;
    public override string Value {
        get { return _value; }
    }
    public void set_Value(string value) {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

In `ConcreteClass1`, I get an error on the `set`. It can't override `set_Value` because no overridable set accessor exists in AbstractClass.

In `ConcreteClass2`, I get an error on both `Value`'s because a member with the same name is already declared.

`ConcreteClass3` doesn't give an error, but even though Value's set accessor would be compiled into set_Value, it doesn't work the other way around. Defining a `set_Value` does not mean that `Value` gets a set accessor. So I can't assign a value to a ConcreteClass3.Value property. I *can* use ConcreteClass3.set_Value("value"), but that's not what I'm trying to achieve here.

Is it possible to have the abstract class demand a public getter, while allowing an optional setter to be defined in a derived class?

*In case you'r wondering, this is just a theoretical question. I don't have a real situation where something like this is needed. But I can imagine an abstract class that doesn't care how a property gets set, but that does need to be able to get the property.*

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do exactly what you want. You can do this with interfaces though:

```
public interface IInterface {
    string MyProperty { get; }
}

public class Class : IInterface {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The way I would do it is to have a separate SetProperty method in the concrete classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract string Value { get; }
}

public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass {

    private string m_Value;
    public override string Value {
        get { return m_Value; }
    }

    public void SetValue(string value) {
        m_Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `interface`, I can't implement the `DoSomething` method in my base class (there is no base class, just an interface). Using `SetValue` is the same as the `set_Value` in my `ConcreteClass3`. But if that's the way to go, naming it `SetValue` is probably better than `set_Value`.

Comment: The reason set_Value isn't linked to the property is there's an explicit `PropertyDef` definition in the assembly that links the `get_` and `set_` methods; simply naming a method `set_` doesn't link it to a property. There's no way to do exactly what you want in C#; you will have to compromise.

Comment: You can implement `DoSomething` as an extension method on `IInterface`.  See my edit.

Comment: Does this difference in the way derived properties work between abstract classes and interfaces stem from the Common Language Specification or is it implementation specific?

Comment: Although highly voted this solution is completely useless if the only reason you need a `set` is to make it work with a property grid which doesn't understand methods.

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution:  [How to override a getter-only property with a setter in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210971)

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int X { get; }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override int X { get { return 0; } }
}
/*public class C : B  //won't compile: can't override with setter
{
    private int _x;
    public override int X { get { return _x; } set { _x = value; } }
}*/
public abstract class C : B  //abstract intermediate layer
{
    public sealed override int X { get { return this.XGetter; }  }
    protected abstract int XGetter { get; }
}
public class D : C  //does same thing, but will compile
{
    private int _x;
    protected sealed override int XGetter { get { return this.X; } }
    public new virtual int X { get { return this._x; } set { this._x = value; } }
}
```

`D` is now equivalent to a class inheriting from `B` while also being able to override in a setter.

Comment: While it seems to work technically it does look a bit over-complicated compared to simplicity of the accepted answer. Can't imagine convincing my team to use it just to have some properties settable for testing purpose :) But have an up vote for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `protected` access modifier instead. Because of inheritance you are not allowed to use `private`. It looks like so:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int prop { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public override int prop { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you left out the half part of the answer, where the class can set a value to _prop_.

Comment: How would the derived class (`B`) be able to implement a public setter for `prop`?

Comment: @comecme, just leave it like `public int prop { get; set; }`

Comment: If class A has `{get; protected set;}`, and I create class B with an `public override int prop {get; protected set;}` it does not compile. I can't override the property with a protected setter by one with a public setter.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but it's the closest you can get without doing something like you have in concreteclass3

```
public class Concrete : AbstractClass
{
    public new void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected AbstractClass()
    {
        try
        {
            var value = Value;
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Value's getter must be overriden in base class");
        }
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Must be override in subclass
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you define a `new DoSomething` in the concrete class. Also, you'r solution will throw an exception at runtime, at compile time the absence of a Value implementation won't be noticed at all.