# How to override a getter-only property with a setter in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding, readonly, setter, getter

***Update*:**  This question has been revised to make it clearer.  The answers below seem to reflect that this method works well.  Hopefully this question can help people who need to add a `get` or `set` to an existing property.

---

Ran into a problem today where I needed to override a base class's `get`-only property with both a `get` and `set`.  Current consensus seems to be that this is impossible, but I think that I found a method.

The general idea is to make a `new` property instead of directly `override`ing the old one, then we create a bridge method that `override`s the old `get` method with a call to the new one.

#### Situation

Here's some code for an arbitrary pre-existing type structure that can't be modified.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int X { get; }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override int X { get { return 0; } }
}
```

#### Problem

We'd like to write this code, but it won't compile.

```
public class C : B    // won't compile: X can't have a 'set' method
{
    private int _x;
    public override int X { get { return _x; } set { _x = value; } }
}
```

#### Solution

We write the code we want anyway, but we declare the property to be `new` instead of `override`, allowing us to declare a `set` method.

```
public class D : C    // Same thing, but will compile because X is 'new'
{
    private int _x;
    public new virtual int X { get { return this._x; } set { this._x = value; } }  // also 'virtual', unless we want to 'sealed' it.

    //  Bridge method provides the override functionality:
    protected sealed override int XGetter { get { return this.X; } }  // 'sealed' because this bridge should always refer to the new 'get' method
}
```

The extra bridge method, `XGetter`, provides the `override`.  This is glued to the base class structure using an intermediate layer:

```
public abstract class C : B  //abstract intermediate layer
{
    //  Override-and-seal the base property's getter.
    public sealed override int X { get { return this.XGetter; }  }

    //  Define the bridge property for the new class to override.
    protected abstract int XGetter { get; }
}
```

I think that `D` is now equivalent to a class inheriting from `B` while also being able to override in a setter.  Is this correct?

Comment: Practically this will work but Theoretically this is incorrect, the correct thing to do is to add the setter in the abstract class A.

Comment: @Consult Yarla:  Base class `A` has other inheriting classes for which setting the property isn't possible.  If the base class allowed for the property to be set, then there would have to be a dummy implementation of the setter for the classes which don't need it.

Comment: Prior question where people discussed why overriding a getter-only property with a getter/setter isn't possible:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82437

Comment: Can use a similar approach for overriding methods with derived types:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with your solution as it hides the original intent for A and B.  That being said, your solution does work, even when casting to base classes.

Example:

```cs
D d = new D();
d.X = 2;
B b = d as B;

Assert.AreEqual(2, b.X);
```

If the base classes can be modified, I recommend using reflection.

Comment: The base class doesn't have a setter because it's not always meaningful.  In my case the base class is a `Matrix` where the property gets matrix elements at row `i` and column `j`.  Some matrices, like simple struct-like ones, can set these elements.  Other matrices, like `JacobianMatrix : Matrix`, can't allow individual elements to be set.  Separately, why would you recommend reflection?

Comment: I would recommend reflection if you can modify the base class A.  If, instead of using a default getter, base abstract A implemented a field, it could be changed through reflection without all these extra classes.

Comment: I think that your example gets a null-exception error as `D d = b as D;` sets `d` to `null` since `b` isn't a `D`.

Comment: @Nathan R. I don't follow you. Won't d always be null?

Comment: You're right, I typo'ed that one.  I've edited my post.

Comment: @Nathan R: The assert in this edited post is returning `true`.  When `b.X` is checked, it goes to the maximum override which is `c.X`, which goes to `c.XGetter`, which goes to `D.XGetter`, which goes to `D.X`'s getter, which returns `D._x`, which was set by `d.X = 2`.  It all seems to work.

Comment: Yes, I modified my post.  Your solution does work.  My only suggestion is to be careful as it hides the original intent of A.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
The following is *INCORRECT*.

No.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int X { get; }

    public int GetXPlusOne()
    {
        return X + 1;
    }
}
```

You won't change the value of `A.X`.

```
var d = new D();
d.X = 10;

d.GetXPlusOne() == 1
```

Comment: @Keith. I tried this and I think you are wrong, it does work.

Comment: Learn something new every day! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing the new property XGetter in your example, you've made the solution more complex than it needs to be. You can introduce the same property and just reverse which property gets the getter and setter.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int X { get; }
}
public class D : A
{
    private int _x;
    public sealed override int X { get { return XGetterSetter; } }
    public virtual int XGetterSetter { get { return this._x; } set { this._x = value; } }
}
```

There's just as much code in class D in the above example as there is in your original example. This just eliminates the need for class B and class C from your example.

Semantically, this solution may not be the same. You'd have to set the XGetterSetter property as opposed to the X property. Derived classes of D would also have to override XGetterSetter as opposed to X.

Comment: You're right that we can omit the abstract intermediate layer, `C`, if we're willing to accept new semantics, though my concerns would be (1) breaking `interface`s since they'd be affected by semantic alteration and (2) confusing the user with seemingly redundant properties.  Separately, I'd note that `B` wasn't "needed"; both `A` and `B` were pre-existing and just there to illustrate the solution (which was the combination of `C` and `D`).