# C# Possible to override a return type on derived classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

```
class base{
    ....
    public string name();
    ....
}

class deriveda : base{
    ....
    public override string name();
    ....
}

class derivedb : base{
    ....
    public override string name();
    ....
}

class derivedc : base{
    ....
    public override foo name();
    ....
}
```

In most of my derived classes it's consistent but one of them I want to return a custom class type, is this possible?

Comment: You're probably getting a "return type must match" error, right? There's your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Think of it, how will you use it later?

```
base b = new derivedc ()
```

And then? what will be the return type of `b.name()` ? `string`? `foo`?

You can however use generics to control it (although i'm not sure if it'll fit your use case):

```
class base<T>{
    ....
    public virtual T name();
    ....
}

class deriveda : base<string>{
    ....
    public override string name();
    ....
}

class derivedb : base<string>{
    ....
    public override string name();
    ....
}

class derivedc : base<foo>{
    ....
    public override foo name();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Note: name in the base class must be marked virtual. Otherwise, this code works, in the general sense, no idea about the questioner's specific case.

Answer (score 3):

In c# 9, **yes** this should be possible, as long as the new type satisfies the covariance rules, in particular a more derived reference-type. It'll just work.

Comment: Thats awesume!!

Answer (score -1):

**No**, this is not possible. As pointed out by others, the compiler cannot distinguish between functions that differ only in return type (as return type is not part of the function signature).

One workaround (that might not work in your case) is to have your return type be a subclass of the base class functions's return type, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313097/how-to-override-method-with-derived-return-type-in-c?rq=1). However, foo cannot derive from string, because string is a sealed class. The closest you can get to deriving from predefined types like string is to define a string extension method as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910108/how-to-extend-c-sharp-built-in-types-like-string).

Ofir's answer is probably your best choice, but this might give you other ideas.

Comment: the return type is not part of the method's signature and therefore overloading won't work here.

Comment: How could the compiler do overload resolution on `var x = o.name();`?

Comment: @Tim (ref: a deleted comment), there is no signature difference between `public int A()` and `public long A()`. The signature is `A()`. If you define both of these, the compiler would not know which you intended to call and therefore your code could not compile.

Comment: @tim method signature is composed of the method name and its parameters. The return type is not part of it.

Comment: My apologies, I did not know this. It's not an entirely unreasonable assumption, considering that in most other languages, the return type is part of the signature.

Comment: @Tim, not in Java, which is the closest match for C#, at least in origination.