# How can I use a base type's methods, which return an object of the base type, in my derived type?

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to create a class, `ExtendedDataFrame`, by inheriting `DataFrame` from `Microsoft.Data.Analysis`.  The goal is to add a `Name` property:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;

namespace Testing;

public class ExtendedDataFrame : DataFrame
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public ExtendedDataFrame() : base() { }

    public ExtendedDataFrame(string name) : base() => this.Name = name;

    // Implement DataFrame's constructors:
    public ExtendedDataFrame(string name, params DataFrameColumn[] columns) : base(columns)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    
    public ExtendedDataFrame(string name, IEnumerable<DataFrameColumn> columns) : base(columns)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

I can build an `ExtendedDataFrame`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringDataFrameColumn col = new("foo", 0);
        col.Append("bar");
        col.Append("baz");

        ExtendedDataFrame edf = new("EDF", col);

        ...
     }
}
```

But I have lost some functionality.  `DataFrame` has a `Clone` method.  I can use `DataFrame`'s `Clone` method to create a `DataFrame`:

```
// Note: Clone() returns a DataFrame object.
DataFrame df = edf.Clone();
```

However, if I cannot use `DataFrame`'s `Clone` method to create an `ExtendedDataFrame`:

```
ExtendedDataFrame edf2 = (ExtendedDataFrame)df.Clone();
```

This results in a `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.Analysis.DataFrame' to type 'DataFrameExtension.ExtendedDataFrame'.`

This make sense because `Clone` is returning a `DataFrame` object and `edf2` is an `ExtendedDataFrame`.

This brings me to my question.  Other than `Clone`, `DataFrame` has other methdos (like `Filter`) that return `DataFrame` objects.  Is there some way I can use those methods with `ExtendedDataFrame` objects?  Or, is there another means of adding a `Name` property to `DataFrame`?

Comment: If you're trying to get an instance of the derived class from an instance of the base class then it sounds like you need to define your own copy constructor. As for methods like `Filter`, they are not virtual and they create new `DataFrame` objects, so there doesn't appear to be any way have them return new or existing instances of your derived class.

Comment: I would post to the github project. Either a new issue or in something like https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/6144

Comment: @user18387401 I hadn't considered using a copy constructor.  I'll give that a try, thank you.

Comment: The copy constructor is not ideal, as it means you will still be creating an extra object, but, if it's the only way, it's the only way. Note that you will also have access to private members of the source base object in the copy constructor, which may be important.

Comment: Grabbing the source code for DataFrame may ease your task; it may be [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/archive/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis) or may now be maintained at a different location (I didn't look very hard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’re trying to augment the functionality of ‘DataFrame’ by adding additional stuff (like the Name property) and still use the underlying DataFrame logic like Clone() and Filter(), **but** you wish to also augment those methods to return instances of ‘ExtendedDataFrame’ instead of ‘DataFrame’.

You might consider a [composition approach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to give you greater control over your augmented class’s public API. The issue with plain inheritance is you can’t change the return type of Clone(), Filter(), etc. without some [smelly workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313097/how-to-override-method-with-derived-return-type-in-c).

Using composition, you take in as a parameter (or create internally) a DataFrame object, and wrap all functionality in your own custom functionality.

Like so:

```
public class ExtendedDataFrame {
    private readonly DataFrame _dataFrame;
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ExtendedDataFrame(string name) {
        this.Name = name;
        this._dataFrame = new DataFrame();
    }

    protected ExtendedDataFrame(string name, DataFrame dataFrame) {
        this.Name = name;
        this._dataFrame = dataFrame;
    }


    public ExtendedDataFrame Clone() {
        return new ExtendedDataFrame(this.Name, this._dataFrame.Clone());
    }

    // Other methods here

}
```

The caveat is, any DataFrame methods you want to be exposed on your augmented data frame class, you need to manually create methods in your class that call the method on the underlying data frame.

Comment: Thanks @brads3290, this approach would solve my problem despite the caveat.