# having two indexers in a derived class with int and long parameters

Tags: c#, abstract-class, indexer

In the following program, think of  `A` is a class provided through dlls and so there is no way to change it. Class `B` needs to be derived from A. It has to implement the abstract class's indexer. But the indexer has only a `get` section and I also need a `set` section which is not allowed for the implementation. So I tried to add an indexer with `long` parameter type to complement the the overridden indexer. But now, `int a = b[10]`has an error in the following program. What is wrong and how can I remove this error?

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract int this[int i]  { get; }
}
class B : A
{
    public int a;
    public override int this[int i]
    {
        get => i;
    }
    public int this[long i]
    {
        set => a = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        int a = b[(int)10];
    }
}
```

Removing `long` indexer removes the error! Why does it hide the `int` indexer completely?

Comment: Why do you need a separate indexers for getter and setter?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski CS0154 The property or indexer 'B.this[long]' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Comment: Unfortunately indexer support in C# kinda sucks. You simply can't do this. You can always provide a new `Set...` method or an explicitly named property for aliasing the `this`, but you cannot make `b[..] = ...` compile. There are [rather complicated workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22210971/4137916) for regular properties, but those won't work for indexers (without losing the indexer syntax, at least). If `A` were an interface it would be a completely different matter, of course, as then adding a setter would work out of the box.

Comment: @JeroenMostert My problem is that the `long` indexer has nothing to do with the `int` indexer but completely hides it.

Comment: Interestingly, the error is also resolved when B isn't derived from A and this[int i] is defined without override.

Comment: Those are the rules for overload resolution. If more than one method applies, preference is given to the most derived one, *before* preference is given to better matches of the argument type. Indexers do not behave differently with respect to methods here; you'll get the same behavior if you define `f(int i)` in `A` and `f(long i)` in `B`. The reasoning here is that adding a method to a base class should not suddenly result in a new method being selected for existing code. It avoids one type of brittle base class problem, at the expense of things like this.

Comment: Unfortunately whether `get` or `set` is being invoked doesn't change which indexer is selected either; resolving the indexer happens before that is applied. This is why you will always get the `long` indexer as long as you invoke it with something that could match a `long` argument, regardless of what's declared in `A`. As Willy Wonka might say, [it's all there, black and white, clear as crystal](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#indexer-access), but it means you lose.